# How to find the sum of cells in go?

Tags: go

Implement the `function SumCells(cells)`.

Input: an arbitrary collection cells of Cell variables.

Return: a single Cell variable corresponding to summing corresponding elements in every cell in cells.
[image]

```
type Cell [2]float64

func SumCells(cells ...Cell) Cell {
    sum := 0.0
    var c Cell
    c = append(c, cells)
    for rowIndex, row := range cells { // loop through rows
        for cellIndex := range row {
        sum += [rowIndex][cellIndex]
        }
    }
    return c
}
```

Could someone explain how to write this function?

Comment: There are no rows, or slices to append here. Just loop through the cells and add up individual elements

Answer (score 1):

Cell is a single dimensional array or simple array and in `SumCells` ...Cell or []Cell want's an array of Cells `[]Cell{{1,3}, {3, 4}}` so you can simply do this [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Nn54FHh217t)

```
func SumCells(cells []Cell) float64 {
    var sum float64
    for _, cell := range cells {
        sum += cell[0] + cell[1]
    }
    return sum
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Something like this](https://goplay.tools/snippet/DliAxWEPEGK) should do you:

```
func SumCells(cells ...Cell) (sum Cell) {
    for _, c := range cells {
        sum[0] += c[0]
        sum[1] += c[1]
    }
    return sum
}

type Cell [2]float64
```

Or, if you wanted to future-proof yourself in case the number of elements in a `Cell` changes:

```
func SumCells(cells ...Cell) (sum Cell) {
    for _, c := range cells {
        for i, v := range c {
            sum[i] += v
        }
    }
    return sum
}

type Cell [2]float64
```

Answer (score 0):

```golang
// Cell is a 2D point
type Cell [2]float64

// SumCells adds a bunch of cells together
func SumCells(cells ...Cell) Cell {
    var sum Cell
    for _, cell := range cells {
        sum = sum.Add(cell)
    }
    return sum
}

// Cell.Add adds two cells together
// This is a method on the Cell type
func (c Cell) Add(other Cell) Cell {
    return Cell{
        c[0] + other[0], 
        c[1] + other[1],
    }
}
```